# x509 authentication with Active directory using Spring security

Tags: active-directory, spring-security, x509certificate

Hi Iam new to Spring security,
My task is to authenticate a user against active directory by matching username retrieved from the x509 client certificate. 
So far what i did is enabled ssl mutual authentication

That above part is working fine now i have security.xml file in which i have configured everything related to x509 reference and Active directory configuration

```
      <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

             <http > 
              <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ANONYMOUS" requires-     channel="https"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/UserLogin/*"  access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
         <x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="ldapUserService" />  
</http>

<authentication-manager>
         <authentication-provider user-service-ref="ldapUserService" />
 </authentication-manager>

  <bean:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
  <bean:constructor-arg value="ldap://ActiveDirectoryURL:389/CN=example,DC=net"/>
  <bean:property name="userDn" value="mkanaka@example.local"/>
<bean:property name="password" value="secuera1SMK"/>
</bean:bean> 

<bean:bean name="ldapUserService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService">
    <bean:constructor-arg ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
    <bean:constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
</bean:bean>
<bean:bean name="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <bean:constructor-arg value=""/>
    <bean:constructor-arg value="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(objectclass=Users))"/>
    <bean:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean:bean>
<bean:bean name="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" 

class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <bean:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <bean:constructor-arg value="" />
    <bean:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="member={0}" />
    <bean:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
</bean:bean>
```

Now problem i am facing is when i try to retrieve the 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); it's return type is  string rather than userDetails(certificate details used while logging), the string output for getPrincipal() is **anonymousUser** and authorities it give is **ROLE_ANONYMOUS** but when i call getAuthentication.isAuthenticated() it returns **true**.
I am using tomcat 7, Spring security 3.1
What might be the problem please help me in this regard

Comment: This is the expected behaviour for an unauthenticated user. Have you verified that the authentication actually took place successfully (by examining the debug log, for example)?

Comment: I have enabled logging now i could see in log **org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User Mohankumar Kanaka not found in directory**
small hint, my subject DN in the certificate is something like this
**CN=Mohankumar Kanaka,CN=Users,DC=rvalidedc,DC=local** ,  where as the active directory has logon name as **mkanaka@rvalidedc.local** is this is the problem? where has the display for the mkanaka account is Mohankumar kanaka i think it is considered while doing active directory search? Thanks for help luke.

Answer (score 0):

With your configuration, the username which is extracted from the certificate will be "Mohankumar Kanaka" and that is what Spring Security will try to use for authentication.

With your LDAP configuration, it will search for a directory entry with a `sAMAccountName` attribute matching this (which it doesn't find).

You will need some way of mapping the name in the certificate to an Active Directory entry. There's no way Spring Security can do that for you automatically. Ideally part of the subject name in the certificate should match to the AD user name so you can extract it easily.

Comment: Hi,How can we validate the publickey certificate retrieved from the httpservletrequest with the active directory.The configuration given in spring documentation discussing about subject name. please help me in this regard

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really have anything else to add other than what I already wrote. You'll need to explain in your question how the certificates and the AD accounts are connected. If they aren't then obviously you can't validate the certificate against AD.